# Ruby on rails create a single validation and use it everywhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails app and I want to **add a validation of the character's length**.

It is used everywhere in the app where there is a `text field` , And I have many models in the App. Putting everywhere in the model seems repetitive.

> **Can there be any method I can make a single validation and use it anywhere in the model**.

I can't just get a solution in mind so I haven't tried till now 
Would be very thankful If someone can provide the answer

Comment: Is the field you are validating called the same everywhere or you do you want to apply the same validation logic to fields with different names?

Comment: same validation logic to fields with different names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations)

```
# app/validators/char_validator.rb
class CharValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # your validation
  end
end

# app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :bar, presence: true, char: true
end
```

Comment: can i make a char_validator.rb in concerns folder ?

Comment: @user4965201 `app/validators` is a convention. It won't work otherwise.

Comment: By the way, validator is a class, not a module. Why would you want to put it in concerns?

Comment: just because i dont have a validator folder in my existing app, i just have models and the concern folder to use

Comment: @user4965201 just add a new folder in the app directory. There are no problems with that, right?

Comment: yeah there is no problem but who doesnt want a minimal code change in an existing app. I agree with this solution btw. but i am still in search for minimal solution if it exists.

Comment: just one question. how can i get the datatype in the method validate_each

Comment: @user4965201 not sure what you mean. What do you want to do?

Comment: actually i want to check the length of the attribute according to its datatype

Comment: @user4965201 you can pass options to validator like `validates :bar, presence: true, char: :datatype`. And the use it in `validate_each` as `options[:with]`. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use `validates_with` along with custom validator class. More info can be seen at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-with

```
# Your custom validator. Validates that field is all capital letters
class ShoutingValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    options[:fields].each do |field|
      original_value = record.public_send(field).to_s
      uppercase_value = original_value.upcase
      if original_value != uppercase_value
        record.errors.add(field, "#{field} must be shouted in all capital letters.")
      end
    end
  end
end

# Will likely be ActiveRecord::Base in your case Only difference would be to
# remove the `include` and `attr_accessor` lines
class Book
  include ActiveModel::Model
  validates_with ShoutingValidator, fields: [:title, :author]
  attr_accessor :title, :author
end

# Second class to show that the same custom validator can be used
# for other class and field too.
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Model
  validates_with ShoutingValidator, fields: [:name]
  attr_accessor :name
end

# When writing it, i created a test to see that it works
describe Book do
  it 'has shouting title' do
    expect(described_class.new title: 'Non shout').to_not be_valid
  end
end
```

Comment: i can put this shouting_validator.rb file in models folder right ?

Comment: You can put them to models folder but clearer would be to store them under `app/validators`. They get automatically loaded from both places.

Answer (score 0):

You can use concerns for this. You can put your method in the `app/models/concerns` folder, for example, as Validatable module

```
module Concerns::Validatable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def format_website
    Write your validation code here.
  end

end
```

And then include it in each models as

```
include Concerns::Validatable
```

Comment: how can i give the same validation for the different field names in this case ?